# bash passing arguments/parameters?

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments

```
#!/bin/bash

traverse() {
local x=$1
if [ -d $x ]
then
lst=(`ls $x`)
for((i=${#lst[@]}; --i;)); do
    echo "${lst[i]}"
    done
else echo "not a directory"
fi
}

traverse
```

---

I want to pass a parameter such as "/path/to/this/directory/" when executing program but only works if I'm running the program in the same directory as my bash script file and any other parameter I pass is completely ignored.

the script is supposed to take a parameter and check if it's a directory and if it's a directory then list all the files/folders in descending order.  If not display error message.

What is wrong with code, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `$1` in the function refers to `traverse`'s parameters, not your script's parameters.

To run your function once with each argument, use

```
for arg in "$@"   # "$@" is also the default, so you can drop the 'in ..'
do
  traverse "$arg"
done
```

If you in the future want to pass all the script's parameters to a function, use

```
myfunc "$@"
```

This is just the problem at hand, though. Other problems include not quoting your variables and using command expansion of ls, `` lst=(`ls $x`) ``, instead of globs, `lst=( "$x"/* )`

Comment: @[that other guy] thanks very helpful information! now runs as I expected!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `ls` for that. You can use this code:

```
traverse() {
    local x="$1"
    if [ -d "$x" ]; then
        arr=( "$x/"* )
        for ((i=${#arr[@]}; i>0; i--)); do
           echo "${arr[$i]}"
        done
    else
        echo "not a directory"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"That other guy" has the right answer. The reason it always looks at the current directory:

1. you invoke `traverse` with no arguments
2. the `$1` in the traverse function is empty, therefore `$x` is empty
3. the test is therefore `[ -d  ]`, and when `[` is given 1 argument, it returns success if the argument is not empty. Your `if` command always executes the "true" block and `ls $x` is just `ls` when x is empty

Use `[[ ... ]]` with bash: it is smarter about empty arguments. Otherwise, quote your variables:

```
$ x=; [ -d $x ] && echo always true || echo not a directory
always true
$ x=; [[ -d $x ]] && echo always true || echo not a directory
not a directory
$ x=; [ -d "$x" ] && echo always true || echo not a directory
not a directory
```